# material ui buttons effect

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have those two buttons using material ui

```
<Button variant="contained">Apply</Button>
<Button variant="contained">Remove</Button>
```

I want to get some description (what the button do) whene I hover over them and also when I click in one of them the text become bold

Answer (score 1):

You can use `title` attribute:

```
<Button variant="contained" title="I apply!">Apply</Button>
<Button variant="contained" title="I delete!">Remove</Button>
```

For making bold when clicked, you have many ways. Here is the simple CSS solution:

```
<Button variant="contained" title="I apply!" className="apply-btn">Apply</Button>
```

then write CSS like this:

```
.apply-btn:focus {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Notice that you should write your CSS in a separate file. Or you can use `useStyles` if you want to leverage CSS-in-JS.

Comment: Thanks , do you know how I can make the button bold whene I click over it ?

Comment: Thanks , but I want it to change when I click on it not hover over it

Comment: @Yafaa then use `:focus`  in your CSS. I updated my answer.